# F# - string | int inference on union

Tags: f#

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible but thought I'd double check. I guess I'm trying to mimic  typescript's union types.

I have a type

```
type StringOrInt = 
 | String of string
 | Int of int
```

And then a function

```
let returnSelf (x: StringOrInt) = x
```

At the moment the function has to be called like

```
returnSelf (String "hello")
```

Is it possible to do

```
returnSelf "hello"
```

and infer that it is a valid StringOrInt?

Comment: It's not supported yet, but have an [RFC](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/RFCs/FS-1092-anonymous-type-tagged-unions.md). You can join discussion and help implement it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment it's not supported out of the box, but fairly simple generic casting method can be implemented.

Given an example function:

```ml
let call v = (* v has inferred type StringOrInt *)
    match v with
    | String s -> printfn "called a string %s" s
    | Int i -> printfn "called an int %i" i
```

We could eventually call it like so:

```ml
(* % is a unary prefix operator *)
call %"abc" 
call %1
```

We need to provide some way to tell how to convert ordinary string/int into `StringOrInt` type. This can be used by exemplar convention call:

```ml
type StringOrInt =
    | String of string
    | Int of int
    static member inline From(i: int) = Int i
    static member inline From(s: string) = String s
```

Here our discriminated union provides two static methods which are responsible for casting. Since they correspond to the same naming convention, we can use them together with F# statically resolved generic type parameters - these are generics that are resolved at compile time unlike the .NET generics which exists also at runtime - to create a casting function (or operator):

```ml
(* casting operator *)
let inline (~%) (x: ^A) : ^B =
    (^B : (static member From: ^A -> ^B) x)
```

This way you can use `%` prefix operator over any type that implements a casting mechanism in form of static `From` method.